# How i can get multiple files from google drive through the google drive api?

Tags: google-drive-api

I would like to know how i could to obtain multiple files from google drive. I searched this in the reference but i not found this information. I'm building a web application that will talk to drive and retreive a link of a zip file to download. Zip of the files.

I'm using php with api v2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is currently not possible with the Drive API, you have to send multiple requests to retrieve multiple files.

Comment: Is it still allowed on google drive with android api?

Answer (score 2):

I've been faced with a similar problem and while there's currently no way of doing this through Drive (to my knowledge), this is the solution I came up with.

I'm serving up hundreds of thousands of files to clients using a Drive folder as the storage with a custom built front-end built with the Drive API. With that many files, it's ridiculously tedious for users to download files one at a time. So the idea was to let the users select which files they'd like to download and then present them with a zip file containing the files.

To do that, first you'll need to get an array of the Drive files that you want to download whether that's some you generate programmatically or through check-boxes on the front-end. Then you'll loop through that array and grab the 'downloadURL' value for each file and perform a cURL to the url provided. Depending on how many files you're planning on handling per request you can either keep them all in memory or temporarily store them on the disk or in a database. Regardless, once  you have all of the files, you can then zip them up using any number of zip libs that are out there. Then just send the resulting zip file to the user.

In our case we ended up sticking with individual file downloads because of the potentially massive amount of resources and bandwidth this can eat but it's a potential solution if you're not serving large numbers of files.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I am answering the correct query, if you place the files in a folder on google drive, then as far as I know it is possible to download as a complete group of files.