# Retrieving Gdrive Files

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, filesystems, google-chrome-app

I have a public folder in my drive. I need to be able to download the whole folder, keeping the structure intact, and download certain files. I am using the chrome.filesystem api to overwrite some user files with the ones that are downloaded. I am downloading a json from the same folder to determine which files need to be downloaded. I could list the urls to all the files in that json, but that seems inefficient and is annoying. How could the urls be determined in a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to download a whole folder at this moment. I have seen other solutions, for example zipping all the urls and downloading a single zip file. You can read more information on this issue: [How i can get multiple files from google drive through the google drive api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788757/how-i-can-get-multiple-files-from-google-drive-through-the-google-drive-api)